# Check number of list items and columnize if condition exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

Example page: http://vincent-massaro.com/columns/columns.html

On this page, there are two ordered lists, one with four items, and one with eight. I need to write a condition that checks how many list items are in each ordered list, and if it's more than four, split them into columns; if there are less than four, don't split into columns. The code that accomplishes this now is:

$('.mcol', this).makeacolumnlists({cols: 3, colWidth: 0, equalHeight: 'ul', startN: 1});

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One nice way is with a custom selector. Something like this:

```
$.expr[':'].hasmorethan4li = function(obj){
  return $(obj).children('li').length > 4;
};
```

Lets you do this:

```
$('ol:hasmorethan4li').makeacolumnlists(....);
```

---

**Updated:** As per the OP's question from the comments, here's a version of the selector for lists with between 4 and 12 items:

```
$.expr[':'].hasbetween4and12li = function(obj){
  var len = $(obj).children('li').length; // so we only have to run this once
  return len >= 4 && len <= 12;
};
```

Comment: How would I change the condition to say greater than 4 AND less than or equal to 12? This doesn't seem to work:

  return $(obj).children('li').length > 4 && <=12 ;

Comment: Check the length once: `var len = $(obj).children('li').length;`. Then do your more complex comparison: `return len > 4 && len <= 12;`.

Comment: http://vincent-massaro.com/columns/columns.html

Using this right now and I get "Error: obj is not defined". See example page for code.

Comment: This `var len = $(obj).children('li').length;` has to go *inside* each custom selector definition, right before the `return`. We're doing this so it's cached and not run multiple times with each use of a custom selector. I've updated the answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

check the number of li's using `$('li').size()`

Comment: I'm a jQuery newbie and wrote something using .length but it didn't work. I wasn't able to get it to check each li set individually.

Comment: This will give you the *total* number of `<li>` elements on the page.

Comment: $('.mcol').each.length; is a start - but how do I set it to check the number for each OL?

Comment: @user - See my answer. I updated it to use `<ol>` instead of `<ul>`.

Comment: You're right--I was just pointing out the `.size()` method.  You do need to iterate through each ol/ul to make this work per list (as you do in your example).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `length` property of `<li>` elements under a `<ol>`, you need to get it separately for *each* `<ol>`.

```
$('ol').each(function() {
    $(this).children('li').length;  // Gives you the number of <li>
                                    //    elements for the current <ol>
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/each/
- http://api.jquery.com/children/
- http://api.jquery.com/length/